# are the sums of reciprocals of Mersenne's divisors bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $\mathcal{R}_n$ denote the sum of reciprocals of divisors of $2^n-1$:

$\mathcal{R}_1=1$,

$\mathcal{R}_2=1+\frac{1}{3}$,

$\mathcal{R}_3=1+\frac{1}{7}$,

$\mathcal{R}_4=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{15}$,

$\dots$

Is the sequence $(\mathcal{R}_n)$ bounded or not?

(own question, solution unknown, I googled a lot, but didn't found any text containing the answer to this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sequence is not bounded.

Let $p_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ prime, $p_1 = 2$, $p_2 = 3$ and so on. Take any $k$ and set $n = (p_2 - 1) \ldots (p_k - 1)$. Due to Fermat's Little Theorem we have
$$2^n \equiv 1\pmod{p_i}, \qquad i = 2, \ldots k.$$
In other words, $p_i$ is a divisor of $2^n - 1$ for every $i = 2, \ldots, k$. Hence
$$\mathcal{R}_n \ge \frac{1}{p_2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{p_k}.$$
As the series $\sum\limits_{i = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_i}$ diverges, we have that $(\mathcal{R}_n)$ is not bounded.